# Fill every other row based on a non-empty cell?

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, fill

The first column in my spreadsheet comprises empty and non-empty cells. I'd like to take the first non-empty cell AND the immediate empty cells underneath it and fill their rows white. I then want to take the next non-empty cell and the immediate empty cells underneath it and fill their rows grey. I'd like to repeat this white-grey pattern throughout my spreadsheet. How can I do this without going through it manually?

(Example: A1 is non-empty and A2:A5 are empty; I'd like all of these and their rows to have no fill (white). A6 is non-empty and A7:A9 are empty; I'd like all of these and their rows to have a grey fill.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional formatting for this.

Click on cell `A1` then choose *Conditional Formatting* and then *New Rule...*

Choose the option *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and then type this formula into the formula box:

```
= MOD(COUNTA(A$1:A1),2)=0
```

Click the *Format...* button and choose the grey color of your choice.

Then apply this conditional formatting to the entire `A` column.

See below a working demonstration of this.

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To apply this to entire row (instead of just first column of each row), change formula to:

```
= MOD(COUNTA($A$1:$A1),2)=0
```

Comment: This was useful, however it doesn't fill the whole row.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you wanted the entire row. Change formula to `= MOD(COUNTA($A$1:$A1),2)=0` and then you can apply the formatting to the entire sheet. This should fix the problem.